# In Detroit: Become Human, what is ra9?

Tags: detroit-become-human

In the video game [Detroit: Become Human](https://www.quanticdream.com/en/detroit-become-human), many of the deviants become obsessed with something (or someone) called "ra9". Has any source, either in-game or out of game, definitively established what ra9 is?

Comment: https://detroit-become-human.fandom.com/wiki/RA9 - Robot Jesus

Comment: In other words, "No."